# pyInstaller ImportError cannot import name libsvm

Tags: python, pyinstaller, importerror, libsvm

I am using python 3.5.2 and I am trying to convert a .py file to exe by pyInstaller, the executable file when run gives the error

```
ImportError cannot import name 'libsvm'.
```

The error is coming even though I am not using any svm functions.

Comment: Does the script work when you run it under python?

Comment: yeah it works fine under python